# React dropzone clears files

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I am using the React Dropzone library for file uploads. I have noticed that the files clear everytime the file box is clicked. For example, if you add one file, then click the box again to add another file, the original disappears. I have tried using the onDrop function in dropzone but I havent been able to figure that our. I am new to React so I would love some pointers on where to find information on this.

Comment: You can read the usage here  https://react-dropzone.js.org/.

Comment: Share your code. Then we can suggest a more accurate solution.

Answer (score 0):

react [dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/) has an argument name multiple which you can specify if you want to let user select/drag multiple files. the default value for this argument is true so this is how i use the library:

```
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    accept: '.jpeg,.png,.jpg',
    onDrop: acceptedFiles => {
      if (acceptedFiles.length === 0) {
        return;
      }
      const newFiles = acceptedFiles.map(file => {
        return {
          file,
          preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
        };
      });
 let newFilesState = [...files.concat(newFiles)];
    //here i add the previously added files to new state and concat them with newly droped files
    },
  });
```

here is my jsx

```
  <Button onClick={() => {
                inputEl.current.click();
              }}
            >
    <div {...getRootProps()}>
                <input
                  // force input to re-render on file change
                  {...getInputProps()}
                  ref={inputEl}
                />
              </div>
 </Button>
```

note that variable named files is my redux which stores the previously added files. and after i receive a dropped/selected new file(S) is concat them with my files stored in redux

Answer (score 0):

Use state updating function:

setFiles((prev) => [...acceptedFiles, ...prev]);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).